# motoman stack on ros industrial

Tags: ros, ikfast, motoman, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the motoman stack from ros industrial on a fuerte installation. When I compile (with a rosmake), I receive the error "Cannot find required resource: warehouse_ros". I have downloaded and installed warehouse_ros from the git repository located at https://github.com/ros-planning/warehouse_ros.git, but the problem did not go away. Any ideas?

BTW, the reason that I am doing this is to experiment with the Fast_IK solution found at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution. However, when I installed this package, I was missing the sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation and started down a path of installing from git. Any help with the Fast_IK would also be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59772/motoman-stack-on-ros-industrial/) by [Steveb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2079/steveb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears as though you are using a groovy version of ROS-Industrial.  The dependency on warehouse_ros was added for groovy.  Assuming this is the case, I would recommend one of the following:

1. Install the binary ROS-Industrial version for motoman: sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-motoman.
2. Install from source to get the latest functionality (i.e. close to groovy), use the fuerte dev branch: [here](https://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Ffuerte_dev)

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0